# Regex Java Discrepancy

Tags: java, regex

I need to verify a password using reqex. I have written one and tested it in this checker and it works:
http://www.nvcc.edu/home/drodgers/ceu/resources/test_regexp.asp

But when I add it to my Java application, it fails.

Regex in regex checker:(\D+)(\d+)(\D+)(.*)

Regex in java: (\\D+)(\\d+)(\\D+)(.*)

Test string: 1Hello2

This passes in the online checker but fails in Java.

Does anyone know why?

I want the regex to match any password that has a number in its middle (can have them at the start and end too).

I need 2 seperate regex: one that matches digits in the middle (pass1word or 1pass1word or 1pass1word) and also a regex that matches a digit at the start or end (1password or password1 NOT pass1word1 because that is in the string category).

Comment: It doesn't pass in the online checker, and I know why. Namely, `\D` means a non-digit character. To match anything with a number in the middle, use something like `'.+\d+.*'`.

Comment: @Lev: I think you mean `.*\d.*`.

Comment: @NiklasB, you're right. It must have the same effect though.

Comment: @Lev: No, even after the edit it wouldn't match `1hello` for example, although it's a valid password according to OP.

Comment: @NiklasB: ohhh, I misread (misunderstood) your comment. The regex I actually mean is `'.+\d.+'` (too late to edit the first comment now). Your regex matches any password with a digit in it. Mine matches any with a digit *in the middle*, which is how I understand the last sentence of the question.

Comment: "I want the regex to match any password that has a number in its middle (can have them at the start and end too)." Basically you want to match anything with a digit in it :)

Comment: @Lev: "has a number in its middle (can have them at the start and end too)"

Comment: @NiklasB., yes, and we understand it differently. I got that the only mandatory requirement was a digit in the middle. You got that `'1hello2'` will do, too. Probably the OP really means it, but I don't understand why put it this way :) Just say: "match a string with a number". BTW, `\d` is a valid regex for that.

Comment: @Lev: Yeah, `\d` is valid, but doesn't work with `String.matches` in Java (you have to match the prefix and suffix too, here). By the way, `1Hello2` is the exact test string OP gave (saying it should match).

Comment: Thanks for your replies. I need to give the user back feedback on password strength and a password like pass1word is strong, whereas password1 or 1password is medium. I need a regex that says 1pass1word or pass1word1 or 1pass1word1 is strong. Using .+\\d.+ does not work correctly but maybe I'm being too picky. With .+\\d.+, 123password will match when really, it shouldn't because the digits are at the start.

Comment: Think my original post was a bit misleading. I need 2 seperate regex: one that matches digits in the middle (pass1word or 1pass1word or 1pass1word) and also a regex that matches a digit at the start or end (1password or password1 NOT pass1word1 because that is in the string category).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your regex requres:

1. not digit (1 or more times) \D+
2. 1 or more digits
3. One or more non-digits \D+
4. Any character(s) 0 or more times.

Your example contains

1. 1 Digit
2. 5 non-digits
3. 1 digit

I think it is obvious that it does not match the regex: the first element \D+ fails because digit appears in the beginning.

Comment: My solution in the end: Match strong (\\d*)(\\D+)(\\d+)(\\D+)(.*). Match medium: (\\d+)(\\D+)") || (\\D+)(\\d+)") || (\\d+)(\\D+)(\\d+)